# How to copy a master slide?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-impress

I am building a series of master slides in LibreOffice 5.4.2.2. The slides are very similar.

The obvious idea would be to make a single master slide, copy it, and adapt it.

I did not find a way to do that: Ctrl-C seems disabled, and 'Duplicate slide' is disabled, too.

How do I copy a master slide?

Is there a better way of doing very similar master slides (maybe some way of inheriting from a parent master slide)?

Answer (score 4):

If Insert-->Duplicate slide is disabled, try this:

- Save your master slide you want to copy (main.odp)
- Save another copy of it to another file (new.odp)
- Open up the initial (main.odp) file so you have two impress windows open
- Open up the master view in each impress window
- Drag the master you want to make a copy of to the slide canvas in the **center**
  of the impress window (not the left slide pane)
- Now you will have a copy of the slide master you dragged over added to the bottom of the slide pane list

Comment: While this does copy some of the master, it does not copy all information. In my case these are missing: The font and font color in the title field, background color of the slide. So it is clearly a help, but not a 100% solution.

Comment: It worked for me quite well, using LibreOffice 5.4.2. But I can't believe that this is not a standard feature...

Comment: Worked for me too with LibreOffice v7.1.3.2

Answer (score 0):

I think CTRL-C is disabled because of these automatic layout area's. You can resize and move them, but not remove them. They are tied to the slide in some way.

For me it worked best to

- Open the master slide to be cloned
- Copy everything (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>)
- De-select the area's for automatic layout by <kbd>shift</kbd>-clicking them
- Create a new master slide
- Paste